# Kendo UI access detail grid instance from widget in its editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo UI grid, and a child grid(s) nested within the parent one. When I do a popup edit on the child grid and have a dropdownlist select as one of its fields, I want to access from this dropdown the instance of the child grid currently being edited.

It is apparently not feasible to provide id to the child grids (because all child grids would then get the same id) so e.g. I cannot do most straightforward:

```
var childGrid = $("#myChildGridCurrentlyEdited").data("kendoGrid");
```

What I want to get is the observable array from currently edited child grid to check what elements it's got. I will appreciate help, just best check jsFiddle here, code initiating childGrid and its editor here below just for quick view.

https://jsfiddle.net/Turo/7a0LLrdf/1/

---

```
function initDetail(e) {
  $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
    dataSource: [{gender: "male",height: "2m", ageEdit: {Id: 1, Age: 40}}, 
    {gender: "female",height: "1.6m", ageEdit: {Id: 2, Age: 50}}],
    columns: [
    {field: "gender"}, 
    { field: "height"},
    {field:"ageEdit", template: "#= ageEdit.Age #", editor: editAge},
    {command: ["edit"]}],
    editable: {mode: "popup"}
  })
}

function editAge(container, options){
    $('<input required name="ageEdit"/>')
    .appendTo(container)
    .kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "Age", 
    dataValueField: "Id",
   dataSource: [{Id: 1, Age: 20}, {Id: 2, Age: 30}],
   select: function(e){
        alert("how do I get to the detail grid instance from here?")
   }
})
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the detail Grid's [`edit`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-edit) event to [find the DropDownList](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/Editing/access-editor-control) and [`bind`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/widget-basics/events-and-methods#event-binding-after-initialization) its [`select`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#events-select) handler:

```
edit: function(arg) { 
    arg.container
        .find("[name=ageEdit]").data("kendoDropDownList").bind("select", function(j) {
            var detailGrid = arg.sender;
});
```

On a side note, to set an ID to a detail Grid, use the ID value of the respective master row, which is available in the [`detailInit`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-detailInit) event for example:

```
$("<div id='detail-grid-" + e.data.id + "'></div>").appendTo()...
```

The master Grid must have the ID field defined in [`dataSource.schema.model.id`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema.model) for `e.data.id` to work, otherwise you should use the ID field name instead of `id`.

Comment: Thank you,  I actually managed to come to similar conclusions yesteday morning, nice answer.